# Android Layout - Arc Buttons

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I wanted to make a home page like this for an app. The problem is I am not getting the perfect curve which I want, and also this this does not work on other screens. This is the code which I have used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@drawable/Background"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">
    <TextView
        android:text="Mind and Wellness"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:textColor="#ff3e4095"
        android:textColorHighlight="#ffffffff" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp">
    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/space1"
        android:layout_weight="1.5" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_weight="2">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonx"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Find a Solution"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:textColor="#ff3e4095"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp">
    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/space1"
        android:layout_weight="3" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_weight="2">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:background="@drawable/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Tips and Research"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:textColor="#ff3e4095"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp">
    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/space1"
        android:layout_weight="4.5" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_weight="1.5">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:background="@drawable/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Mtyhs and Facts"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:textColor="#ff3e4095"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp">
    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/space1"
        android:layout_weight="6" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_weight="1.5">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:background="@drawable/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Assesments"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:textColor="#ff3e4095"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp">
    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/space1"
        android:layout_weight="7.5" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_weight="1.5">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:background="@drawable/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Distress"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:textColor="#ff3e4095"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp">
    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/space1"
        android:layout_weight="9" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_weight="2">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:background="@drawable/button5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Articles"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:textColor="#ff3e4095"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is a link to the homepage right now [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dSF9.png)
The layout which i want [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvwlz.png)

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the current view or any reference of what you're trying to replicate?

Comment: curve?  what curve?  what are you talking about?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/3ALwNMm.png?1 
This is the homepage

http://i.imgur.com/CqSNpcO.png The source to copy

Comment: Curve in button layout...Once check those images.

Answer (score 0):

You are using too many views and linear layouts which is not good UI Designing,
    Although you can replace your "Button and TextView" with single TextView.

Therefore you can try this layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:text="Find a solution" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:text="Tips &amp; Research" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:text="Myths &amp; Facts" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:text="Assesments" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:text="Distress" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="115dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:text="Articles" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This layout is almost like your layout with less number of Linear Layouts and other Views.

I Hope this helps you somehow.

Comment: Just copy paste my layout and let me know is it helpful to you.

Comment: Thank You A.R. for helping me out.  I am new to this so these are like speed bumps. and one more thing, how can i move the linear layout? i want them in the center as the image above

Comment: You can use   android:gravity="center_horizontal"   under Linear Layout, along with this you need to adjust "margin_left" of other textviews if it requires as per your requirement.